# My final render with cycles look blurry after denoise

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, hdri, denoise

[image: Room image]

I am new to blender and try to make a room everything look good until I use final render to get a high quality picture the light look wrong
I try to use 1 light bounce and it didnt help at all
pls help me impove it
this is a link to the file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xbyjeavqvRbqsibHUftfH_fEZm8niYbh/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

What sample count did you use? If the sample count is low, of course it will look blurry after denouse. This is not related to light bounces at all. If you wan't a sharper image after denoising, you will have to increase your sample count.[image]

At sample counts as low as 128 for the final render, your render will look blurry after denoising. Nice interior by the way.

Comment: My sample counts is 128 it a basic setting i think? so i have to  increase my sample count
I will try. thank u

Comment: @ธนบดีบัณฑิตสุวรรณ Yes. It is a very basic setting for interiors like these. It starts looking better around 350-500 samples and looks very nice at 1000 or above samples.